# My RSA encryption produces 2^64 every time (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption, rsa

I have written an attempt at my own RSA algorithm, but the encryption portion isn't quite working when I use fairly large numbers (nothing like the size which should be used for RSA) and I'm not sure why.

It works in the following way:

The input is a list of characters, for this example "abc"

This is converted to an array: [10,11,12]. (I have chosen 10 - 35 for lower case letters so that they are all 2 digit numbers just to make it easier)

The numbers are combined to form 121110 (using 12*100^2 + 11*100^1 + 10*100^0)

Apply the algorithm: m^e (mod n)
This is simplified using a^b (mod n) = a^c (mod n) * a^d (mod n)

This works for small values in that it can be deciphered using the decryption program which I have written.

When using larger values the output is always 1844674407188030241, with a little bit of research I found that this is roughly 2^64 (to 10 significant figures, it has been pointed out that odd numbers can't be powers of two, oops). I am sure that there is something that I have overlooked and I apologise for what (I really hope) will be a trivial question with an easy answer. Why is the output value always 2^64 and what can I change to fix it? Thank you very much for any help, here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

int returnVal (char x)
{
    return (int) x;
}

unsigned long long modExp(unsigned long long b, unsigned long long e, unsigned long long m)
{
unsigned long long remainder;
int x = 1;

while (e != 0)
{
remainder = e % 2;
e= e/2;

if (remainder == 1)
x = (x * b) % m;
b= (b * b) % m;
}
return x;
}

unsigned mysteryFunction(const std::string& input)
{
  unsigned result = 0;
  unsigned factor = 1;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
  {
    result += factor * (input[i] - 87);
    factor *= 100;
  }

  return result;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long p = 70021;
    unsigned long long q = 80001;
    int e = 7;
    unsigned long long n = p * q;
    std::string foo = "ab";
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.length(); i++);

    {
        std::cout << modExp (mysteryFunction(foo), e, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: You got an odd number and decided it was a power of 2?

Comment: I didn´t look at the code yet, but do you know that 2^64-1 (your value) is the maximum possible number in built-in variables? (except for special hardware/compilers...). Don´t do RSA yourself, there are good libraries already. Openssl ...

Comment: @deviantfan: It's not even 2^64-1.

Comment: You´re right...the beginning is the same, but not the rest and digit count. Hm

Comment: @User2357112 Sorry, **roughly** 2^64, I can't believe I actually typed something so stupid

Comment: @deviantfan If I were encrypting any important data, I definitely wouldn't use what I had written myself. I managed it in Haskell and wanted to see if my C++ was good enough yet, obviously not.

Comment: I've spotted two major problems, the declaration of `x` as an `int` in `modExp` and the fact that `p` and `q` aren't prime. I think the declaration of `x` as `int` is causing undefined behavior somewhere, since I'm not sure how converting an int to unsigned long long could cause the output we're seeing.

Comment: That's the last time I use Wolfram Alpha for my primes and thanks a lot, don't know how I missed that, I'll see if changing these works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems.

Problem 1: Inconsistent use of `unsigned long long`.

```
int x = 1;
```

Changing this declaration in `modExp` to `unsigned long long` causes the program to give a more reasonable-looking result. I don't whether it's the *correct* result, but it's less than `n`, at least. I'm still not sure what the exact mechanism of the error was. I can see ways it would have screwed things up, but none that could have caused an output of 1844674407188030241.

Problem 2: Composite "primes".

For RSA, `p` and `q` both need to be prime. Neither `p` nor `q` is prime in your code.

```
70021 = 7^2 * 1429
80001 = 3^2 * 2963
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need `p` and `q` to be primes, you only need the exponent `e` to be coprime with `φ(n) = φ(pq)`, which clearly isn't.

Answer (score 0):

In `mysteryFunction`, you subtract 89, which corresponds to 'W', from the input characters. You probably want to subtract '97' instead, which corresponds to 'a'.

Comment: I have made a=10, b=11 ... z=35. The ASCII value of a is 97 so I think that 87 is correct? Thanks though, I appreciate the help.